# There is already a data reader open associated with this command even with MARS active

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I have an exception telling me that:

> there is already a datareader open associated with this command that
>   must be closed first

even with MARS enabled in my connection string:

```
Data Source=servername;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=database;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Wasn't MARS supposed to remove this limitation? I'm using C# and SQL Server 2008

Comment: It does. Are you sure your connection string has that? Can you reproduce the problem with a super simple C# console app?

Comment: Note the error: associated with this *command*. MARS allows you to have multiple open data readers on the same *connection*. These must still come from different *commands* (you can have them be the same actual command, but not the same `SqlCommand` object). Is that what's going wrong in your code?

Comment: Can you add more code around the point where the error occurs?  Can you not have one command finish before running another one?

Comment: @JeroenMostert That could be a possibility. The code is really huge, and wasn't me who developed, but I have to maintain. The code is using lazy loading because it's a 76Gb database, so it's really hard to track what is open and what is not. I was confused at first since the connection string has MARS enabled but you gave me a very good clue to follow.

Comment: Good call @JeroenMostert. Curiously, the SAME error message about using the same *command* is used when MARS is off and you aren't using the same command. You'd think with MARS *off* it would say same connection, and with MARS on it would say same command.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you, that was exactly the problem. I you care to answer the question I'll kindly accept it. Thank you so much, it was very clever...